# Cross-validation score of 0

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm new to data analysis so please excuse me if this is a bit of a newbie question. I am running a PLS regression on same data where X comprises of ordinal variables and y is a binary variable indicating whether an event occurred or not. I generated some cross-validation scores and got the following:

```
X = threat.iloc[:,2:96]
y = threat.iloc[:,1]

pls1 = PLSRegression(n_components=10)
result = pls1.fit_transform(X, y)

scoresT = cross_val_score(pls1, X, y, cv=5)
print(scoresT)

[ 0.          0.          0.          0.55965802  0.        ]
```

I know that each number represents the score for each "fold", but I expected a series of numbers like [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.3] rather than [0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0] so I am unsure of what exactly this is saying about my data or model.

Does anyone have any insights?

Comment: You should provide a reproducible minimal example, otherwise it is hardly possible to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the "scoring" parameter in cross_val_score is not specified, it returns the default score method of the estimator. For the PLSRegression (just like for all regression models in sklearn), the [score method](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_decomposition.PLSRegression.html#sklearn.cross_decomposition.PLSRegression.score)

> Returns the coefficient of determination R^2 of the prediction.
>
> The coefficient R^2 is defined as (1 - u/v), where u is the residual sum of squares ((y_true - y_pred) ** 2).sum() and v is the total sum of squares ((y_true - y_true.mean()) ** 2).sum(). The best possible score is 1.0 and it can be negative (because the model can be arbitrarily worse). A constant model that always predicts the expected value of y, disregarding the input features, would get a R^2 score of 0.0.

The reason you are getting no-better-than-constant-model cross validation scores is probably that you are using a regression model to solve a classification problem. Try a classification model instead.